# Add Eclipse standard menus to RCP Product

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-rcp, product

How can add ALL standard eclipse menus (File, Edit...) in my RCP Product? I've got most popular dependencies (eclipse ide, platform...) but I can't see them (only Run and Search).

Answer (score 1):

Your `ActionBarAdvisor` will have to include most of the code from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` to set up all these menus.

You could just use WorkbenchActionBuilder but this is an **internal** class so might change without warning as it is not part of the official API.